# How to detect file extension with javascript FileReader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using javascript's FileReader and my customized function for reading an JPG-JPEG image,
My problem is that how it's possible to detect the file extension through my code below and give error to user if the file is not JPG-JPEG:

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      alert('image has read completely!');
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: No need to actually read the file, just get its [`.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File.name)?

Comment: But I wana read the file first

Comment: Nothing hinders you to also read it, but it's not *necessary* for getting the name

Comment: Note that this is probably an XY problem: you really want to be checking the MIME type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672957/2691058

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can try this,
I changed your code as follows:

```
var fileTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'what', 'ever', 'you', 'want'];  //acceptable file types

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var extension = input.files[0].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(),  //file extension from input file
            isSuccess = fileTypes.indexOf(extension) > -1;  //is extension in acceptable types

        if (isSuccess) { //yes
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                alert('image has read completely!');
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
        else { //no
            //warning
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's not a direct interface to read the file extension. You have at least 2 options:

- Use a regex to extract the extension from the filename
- Use the content type of the file as your filter

For the extension method it'd be something like:

```
var extension = fileName.match(/\.[0-9a-z]+$/i);
```

Comment: I like regex a lot better than splitting strings, and dropping chars, etc.. Thanks for the suggestion!