# Determinate еру type of file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image-uploading, filereader

I use filereader for upload image. I Wrote a check to determine the type of file. I want allow download only images type. But it does not work correctly. Can someone help?

there are my code

```
if (file.type) {
   var photoType = /image.*/;
   if (file.type !== photoType) {
       callback(
           null,
           "File not supported! Try to upload another image"
       );

       return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you check MIME type by using the JavaScript's FileReader?

Comment: Yes i have checked.

Comment: if you check you can filter the image types by using the jpeg,png etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095863/how-to-detect-file-extension-with-javascript-filereader  try the above link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect file extension with javascript FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095863/how-to-detect-file-extension-with-javascript-filereader)

Comment: What is _epy_? Not in the dictionary.