# File type checker using file magic number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, file-type, react-dropzone

I have created a promise to resolve the file type on file upload.

```
const fileTypeChecker = file => new Promise((resolve) => {
  const fileReader = new FileReader()

  fileReader.onloadend = (e) => {
    const arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result)).subarray(0, 4)
    let header = ''
    let type = null
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      header += arr[i].toString(16)
    }
    switch (header) {
      case '89504e47': // png
      case 'ffd8ffe0': // following are jpeg magic numbers
      case 'ffd8ffe1':
      case 'ffd8ffe2':
      case 'ffd8ffe3':
      case 'ffd8ffe8':
        type = 'IMG'
        break
      case 'd0cf11e0': // xls
      case '504b34':   // xlsx
        type = 'XLS'
        break
      case '25504446':
        type = 'PDF'
        break
      default:
        type = 'unknown' // Or you can use the blob.type as fallback
        break
    }
    resolve(type)
  }

  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.slice(0, 4))
})
```

I am using react-dropzone to drop files. The `onDrop` function is defined as

```
  onDrop = async (accepted, rejected) => {
    const file = accepted[0] || rejected[0]
    const fileType = await fileTypeChecker(file)
    let error = ''
    if (fileType === 'XLS') {
      this.setState({
        bulkUpload: {
          files: file
        }
      })
    } else {
      error = 'Please select a valid XLS file'
    }
    if (error) {
      this.setState({
        error
      })
    }
  }
```

Why is the file magic number 504b34 for both .xlsx and .zip files? 
So even if I upload a zip file this is treated as XLS.

Comment: You can't get away with just [reading the file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095863/how-to-detect-file-extension-with-javascript-filereader) for your use case?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue - determining if something is a valid XLSX file based on magic number... did you ever find a solution to this?