# Unable to upload .ppt files even after specifing the mime type

Tags: javascript, jquery, powerpoint, mime-types, uploadifive

I am using uploadifive to upload my files. I am having problem uploading only ppt files while other files specified in the fileType are uploaded. What is going wrong?
here is my code

```
    $(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
        'fileSizeLimit' : 5000,
        'fileType'     : [
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/png',
            'application/pdf',
            'text/csv',
            'text/plain',
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
            'application/mspowerpoint',
            'application/x-mspowerpoint',
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
            'application/msword',
            'application/csv',
            'application/excel'
        ],
        'uploadScript' : '{{url('file/uploads')}}',
        'formData'     : {
            '_token'     : '{{csrf_token()}}'
        },
        'onInit': addFiles
    });

});
```

Even though the ppt mime type is specified I get an error that it is not accepted.Here is a screenshot of the error.
[image]

Comment: What MIME type does the browser thing the file has? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload

Comment: another possible problem is the server does know about the file and doesn't want to serve it?

Comment: @DanielCheung is it possible?

Comment: @RajShakya I've migrated the comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is the server does know about the file and doesn't want to serve it?

You should check your server's settings and add a support for the file extensions.