# How to get a media type from a MIME type?

Tags: javascript

I've got a MIME type, and I want the corresponding media type.

For instance, PDF files can have many mime types:

- application/pdf
- application/x-pdf
- application/acrobat
- applications/vnd.pdf
- application/x-download
- application/download
- text/pdf
- text/x-pdf
- (maybe more?)

I'm looking for a JavaScript library that would tell me that it's a PDF file if I give it any of these MIME types. Is there anything like it?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Do you need a _library_ for this? I think you just need to write a function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload check this..

Answer (score 1):

```
function isPdf(mimeType) {
    var pdfMimeTypes = [
        'application/pdf',
        'application/x-pdf',
        'application/acrobat',
        'applications/vnd.pdf',
        'application/x-download',
        'application/download',
        'text/pdf',
        'text/x-pdf'
    ];

    return pdfMimeTypes.indexOf(mimeType) > -1;
}
```

Comment: I could do that, but I'm pretty sure it has already been done, probably in a better way that I would. I was hoping that there was something kind of official or widely used. [This](https://github.com/rnicholus/determinater) will do.