# Forbidden File Type docx

Tags: javascript, uploadifive

I'm testing the uploadifive plugin file upload restrictions and I cannot seem to get it to accept .docx files. In the documentation (http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/filetype/) I have followed the instructions (bar a small mistake - the pipe "|" character does not work) and have used the media types it refers to (http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). No other file type seems to be causing a problem e.g. .doc, .xlsx.

Is there a solution for this, I have checked multiple sources and the mime type (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document) is correct as far as i can tell?

```
<h1>UploadiFive Demo</h1>
<form>
    <div id="queue"></div>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
    <a style="position: relative; top: 8px;" href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload')">Upload Files</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
            'auto'             : false,
            'checkScript'      : 'check-exists.php',
            'queueID'          : 'queue',
            'uploadScript'     : 'uploadifive.php',
            'fileType' : ['application\/msword', 'application\/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application\/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml','application\/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'],
            'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) { console.log(data); },
            'onError' : function(errorType)
                        {
                            alert('Error: ' + errorType);
                        },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Firefox assigning the MIME type "application/vnd.ms-word.document.12" to the file instead of "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" to .docx files. Chrome and presumably others use the correct one.

This post ([How to check file MIME type with javascript before upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload)) proved helpful to see how the browser is treating it.