# how can I check files (check size&mime type) before upload via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, multipartform-data

I have a multiple input files form.

```
<form id="form" action="index2.php?id=upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input id="files" multiple="true" name="files[]" type="file" />

  </form>
```

I could send several files via this ajax/jquery:

```
$("#files").on('change',(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
     url: "index2.php?id=upload",
     type: "POST",
     data:  new FormData($("#form")[0]),
     contentType: false,
     cache: false,
     processData:false,
     beforeSend : function()
     {

     }
```

it works,But how can I check files (check size&mime type) before upload them and warning to users?

Comment: Although OP asks for a jQuery implementation. I think this question is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload.