# Verifying url has pdf file

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I would like to know how I can check if a url with a certain file has the pdf extension, in my code if the url has a pdf file a modal will be opened, if it is any other extension nothing happens.

I tried doing this using: if (/pdf/.test(document.file))

As document.file the link from my file.

But something is wrong, maybe the syntax of the code I should be confused with the + and the "" in the html part.

My code is:

```
for(var key in data.val()){
    documento = data.val()[key]
    linha = "<tr>"+
    "<td>"+documento.titulo+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+documento.data_inicio+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+documento.categoria+"</td>"+
       if (/pdf/.test(documento.arquivo)){+
           "<td class='view'><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-link='"+documento.arquivo+"'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></a></td>"+
        }+
        "</tr>";

        $('#tableCustom tbody').append(linha);  
        $(".view a").on( "click", function() {
            var link = $(this).data('link');
            PDFObject.embed(link, ".modal-content");
        });                         
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to concatenate an if statement into your string. That is all sorts of broken... check out the ternary operator as a alternative to you if...

Comment: try to change `/pdf/` with `/\.pdf$/` https://regex101.com/r/2TTWBQ/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the if statement inside string concatenation. So it is a syntax error.

What you could do:

- Create variable, which holds an empty string
- Use the `.indexOf()` method like @Mason Wright suggested.
- If it has the pdf extension build your string by using the newly created variable
- Use the variable in string concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use .indexOf() and that would tell you if there is a ".pdf" in the url

```
if (documento.arquivo.indexOf(".pdf") != -1) {
    // It is a pdf 
}
```

Comment: or `'pdffile.pdf'.split('.').pop() == 'pdf'`

Comment: and how do you handle such pdfs https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/5qOCEpKzQldoRsVatUPS ?

Comment: @AlexBota if the URL string does not contain hints about what it is, you could fetch the file and get its meme type from it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679681/getting-a-file-type-from-url

Comment: @MasonWright thanks for pointing me in the right direction