# Is it possible to detect file extension change with Javascript during HTML upload

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I have a hypothetical question. I currently am using **AngularJS** in my application and I am using a third party module, **ng-file-upload**, for file uploads. Now obviously I can check the file extension of the uploaded file and exclude it / prevent it from being sent to the server should it be undesirable, for example I only wish to allow the upload of images and the user uploads a word document. However I was thinking. Should a malicious user change a file from say "`nastyfile.exe`" to "`nastyfile.gif`" the malicious file would pass my check/validation using the `File.type` property as the `File.type` would be `image/gif`. To my knowledge there is no way on the frontend I could check if the original file extension has been modified using JavaScript. Is this the case or is there a way to determine this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This really helped... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an image.
Then listen `error & load event` if `load` trigger, it is an image, else if `error` trigger it is not an image ;)

```
var img = new Image();

img.onerror = function() { /* not an image */ }
img.onload = function() { /* it is an image */ }

img.src = 'PATH/FILENAME';
```