# NodeJS/Formidable : secure the backend for images upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-uploading, formidable

I'm using NodeJS/Formidable and I try to secure my backend for the upload of images.

The classical way to check if the file is an image is to use a regexp like this :

```
if(!file.name || file.name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/i)) {
    console.log("the file is an image");
}else{
    console.log("the file is not an image");
}
```

and this :

```
var fileType = file.type.split('/').pop();
if(fileType == 'jpg' || fileType == 'png' || fileType == 'jpeg' ){
    console.log("the file is an image");
} else {
    console.log( 'incorrect file type: ' + fileType );
}
```

This a good check but this is not enough to be secure; in fact if I rename a PDF as a JPG for example, the browser provide a MIME/type : image/jpg based on the extension of the file.
This is a security issue because you can rename a JS file or whatever to JPG and upload it in your backend filesystem.

I found this really interesting post : [How to check file MIME type with javascript before upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload)

It's perfect for the client side check but I'm not able to reproduce this in my backend.

I guess the ideal way is to analyse the stream on the fly and check the real MIME type after the upload of the first 4 bytes.

Any idea ?

Thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use something like the [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) npm package which takes a buffer (at least the first 4100 bytes) and will return you the MIME type and the file extension:

```
const fileType = require('file-type')
fileType(buffer) //=> {ext: 'png', mime: 'image/png'}
```

Answer (score 2):

It works !
You can install a module like [readChunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-chunk) to transform the file into a buffer and write something like that  :

```
form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    buffer = readChunk.sync(file.path, 0, 4100);

    filetype = fileType(buffer);

    if(filetype.ext.match(/(jpg|jpeg|png)$/i)) {
        fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));
    }else {
        fs.unlink(file.path);
    }

});
```