# How can I sort images by length and width in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that downloads images from a certain website, and then presses the "next" button to go to the next page, and download images from there. Though I would like to only download 1 image, that does not have a recurring class or Id. I would like to do this by filtering the specific image by length and width.

I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42648682) code, and would like to know where it fits in in my code:

```
for( i=0; i < document.images.length; i++)
{ 
  width = document.images[i].width;
  height = document.images[i].height;
  console.log("Image number: " + i + " Size: " + width + "x" + height);
}
```

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
  let urlfilename1 = tabs[0].url.replace('http://127.0.0.1:5500/1%20test/', '').replace('.html', '.png').replace('/',' ').replace('?','');



chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
  let url = tabs[0].url;

  const scriptCodeCollect =
  `(function() {
        // collect all images 
    let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
        let srcArray = Array.from(images).map(function(image) {
            return image.currentSrc;
        });
        chrome.storage.local.get('savedImages', function(result) {
                // remove empty images
                imagestodownload = [];
                for (img of srcArray) {
                    if (img) {
                        img.substring("data:image/".length, img.indexOf(";base64"));
                        console.log(img);   
                    }imagestodownload.push(img);
                };
                result.savedImages = imagestodownload;
                chrome.storage.local.set(result);
                console.log("local collection setting success:"+result.savedImages.length); 
            });
    })();`;

    const scriptCodeDownload =
    `(function() {
      chrome.storage.local.get('savedImages', function(result) {
        let message = {
          "savedImages" : result.savedImages
        };
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message, function(){
          console.log("sending success");
        });
        
      });
      })();`;

      function injectTheScript() {
        // Gets all tabs that have the specified properties, or all tabs if no properties are specified (in our case we choose current active tab)
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            // Injects JavaScript code into a page
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"});
        });
    }
    // adding listener to your button in popup window
    document.getElementById('flipbtn').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
    


document.getElementById("startbtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
if((url.includes('http://127.0.0.1:5500/1%20test/physics/'))) {
    document.getElementById("success").innerHTML = "<strong><u>In progress<br></u></strong> Currently downloading: <br>" +urlfilename1
    startTime = Date.now() - elapsedTime;
  timerInterval = setInterval(function printTime() {
    elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
    print(timeToString(elapsedTime));
  }, 10);
  
      setInterval(function(){ //Loops download
        
      
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
          let urlfilename = tabs[0].url.replace('http://127.0.0.1:5500/1%20test/', '').replace('.html', '').replace('?','');
              document.getElementById("success").innerHTML = "<strong><u>In progress<br></u></strong> Currently downloading: <br>" +urlfilename
          let bk = tabs[0].url.replace('http://127.0.0.1:5500/1%20test/', '').replace('.html', '').replace('/',' ').replace('?', '').replace(/\D/g, '');

        chrome.storage.local.set({'foo': urlfilename, 'bar': bk }, function() {
          console.log('Settings saved');
          console.log(urlfilename);
        });
        function sleep (time) {
          return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
        }
        

        sleep(5000).then(() => {  //Pauses so URL can write and display correctly
          chrome.tabs.executeScript({code : scriptCodeCollect}); //Collects Image
          
          let textCollect = document.getElementById('textCollect');
          chrome.storage.local.get('savedImages', function(result) {
            textCollect.innerHTML = "collected "+ result.savedImages.length + " images"; 
          });
        });

        sleep(10000).then(() => {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript({code : scriptCodeDownload}); //Downloads Image
          document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "test"
        });

          sleep(15000).then(() => { //Waits so image can download fully
              chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"}); //Injects Script to flip page
          });
        });
        });
    }, 20000); //Waits 10s and then loops
  

}
else {
    document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "<strong><u>WARNING:</u></strong><br> Make sure all steps are completed"}
});
```

background.js

```
let downloadsArray= [];
let initialState = {
    'savedImages': downloadsArray
};
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [
                new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                    css: ['img'],
                    css: ['img[input[type="image"[aspect-ratio[attr(1000)/attr(1419)]]]]'],
                    css: ['id[image]']
                })],
            actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
        }]);
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set(initialState);
    console.log("initialState set");
});


//chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function() {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['foo', 'bar'], function(items) {
        var urlfilename = items.foo
        console.log(urlfilename)
        var bkpg= items.bar
//  });

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(message, callback) {
        console.log("message coming");
        console.log(message);
        let srcArray = message.savedImages;
        var counter = bkpg-1;
        for (let src of srcArray) {
            console.log(src);
            chrome.downloads.download({url:src, filename:urlfilename + ".png"});
        };
    });
    });
```

Or is there a better way of filtering images?