# Correctly determine correct file type client side in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I upload a file and catch the event client side for parsing I'm hitting a wall with files with wrong extension.

Here is a snippet I'm using to determine the file type

```
        var input = event.target;
        var files = input.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            console.log(files[i].type);
        }
```

The output I get when running this code is

> application/vnd.ms-excel

when uploading a *.xls file. I know this is a *.tsv file that is wrongly renamed to *.xls.

When running

> file -I 111.xls

in the terminal I get the following output

> 111.xls: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

showing me the correct header of the file.

Is there any way to get the correct file type client side, and not just a mime type based on the extension?

Comment: You would have to replicate / do-something-similar-to what `find` does and start looking inside the file for "magic" values at certain positions to try and estimate what type of file it is.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18299806/2096401) for some suggestions.

Comment: Thanks that worked great after some reading