# Why WAV format doesn't have same mimetype in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, mime-types, wav

File input give different Mimetype for the same file in chrome or firefox. I have a wav file that I want to upload, chrome says it is `audio/wav` and firefox detect `audio/x-wav`.

I know those two mimetype are very similar (`x-` stands for [non-standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Unregistered_x._tree)), but why are they handled differently in this case?

Here is a fiddle to illustrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/r9ae0zfd/. And here is the WAV file I used for this example: https://freesound.org/people/zagi2/sounds/391828/.

In the end the behavior that I would like is to take a `.wav` file from my computer (client) and send it by HTTP to my server as `audio/wav` regardless of the browser.

There's a subsequent question to this: *how to harmonize this behavior?*

Comment: The fiddle uses a file that you want to *up*load?

Comment: The x stands for e**X**perimental

Comment: What version of Firefox? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=306471 was only recently closed.

Comment: @Bergi yes (this 15 chars min policy is soooo relevent)

Comment: @Quentin thanks for the link, pretty related! Though I think my file where downloaded as `audio/wav`, not `audio/x-wav` (I tried on a bunch of different files from different sources). But in the end I still get `audio/x-wav` format from firefox. I use Firefox 54.0

Comment: @UlysseBN What 15 chars min policy?

Comment: Stack Overflow's 15 min chars for a comment, this is out of scope though

Comment: Why do you need this mimeType ? Browsers only check for extensions to set it, any file with extension `.wav` will have its `type` set to one of these. If you want to check if it's a real `audio/wav` file, then check for its magic number : `52 49 46 46`. (`let r = new FileReader(); r.onload = e => console.log(new DataView(r.result).getUint32(0).toString(16) === '52494646'); r.readAsArrayBuffer(file.slice(0,8));}`)

Comment: @Kaiido I send asis to my server that doesn't accept `x-wav`. My solution was to accept x-wav on back-end, but I still want to find out the difference and if there a way to harmonize it. You could make an answer about the magic number, I think it would be pretty appropriate!

Comment: Well no I don't think an answer made of this would be appropriate. Your question is "why is it different between chrome and FF ?" The current answer makes a good point explaining at least 60% of the problem. The other 40% are that there is no official (i.e IANA supported) mimeType for this extension. If you had written your question as the real question you want to be answered, it would be a duplicate of this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload

Comment: And while I know the answer to your edit (simply change `console.log` to `if` and add `file = new Blob([file], 'audio/wav')` after the closing `)` in my first comment), I don't think it is correct to edit your question after someone (quite correctly) answered a previous version of it.

Comment: @Kaiido you're right and I think I'll accept this answer anyway. But there still was a misunderstanding (even without the edit) on this answer. So IMHO clarifying was mandatory. Anyway, his answer with your clarifying comments are both what I wanted so thank you!

Comment: ps: I had a typo : `file = new Blob([file], {type:'audio/wav'})`

Answer (score 12):

Its important to understand that when you've stored a file on disk, the mime type is *not stored within that type*. Thats why we have file extensions like `.jpg` or `.wav`. In the internet over HTTP we don't need them. We can have an URL `http://example.com/foo.wav` but send out a JPEG with the correct the JPEG mime type, and the browser will correcty render it as JPEG. It doesn't care about the file extension.

However if you are on your local file system the file extension is relevant. If you open a file called `foo.wav` your operating system decides by the extension `.wav` to open some audio player.

When selecting a file to upload it to the internet the bowser does a non-trivial task: It selects a mime type for the file extension. For this every browser has a mapping table, mapping known file extensions to mime types. Well, and here is the catch: this table obviously isn't identical on different browsers. So thats why you get different results in your fiddle.

Some browsers map `.wav` to `audio/wav` and some to `audio/x-wav`.

---

So if your test case is downloading a file with the mime type `audio.wav` and then inspecting its mime type with the fiddle you posted you don't check what mime type was sent by your server when you downloaded the file, but only what mime type is guessed for the file extension by your browser.

In both cases, if you sent out a file `foo.wav` with the mime type `audio/wav` or `audio/x-wav` the file on your disk will be identical, and it won't be possible later to know what was the mime type your server sent for the file.

The only thing your browser can do during download is to change the file extension. For example if you sent a file `http://example.com/foo` and it has `audio/wav` as a mime type the browser will probably rename it to `foo.wav`.

Comment: That's very interesting thank you !! Though I'm not downloading a file from my server to a client, but uploading from a client to my server. I'll try to edit my question to make it more clear. Basically I have a `.wav` on my computer (client) that I want to send as `audio/wav` to my server regardless of the browser. Is there a way to achieve that ?

Comment: Also do you have a link where you took information on this browser mapping difference somewhere ?

Comment: Well, if you're only uploading the case is much simple, but the answer stays. the browser maps the `.wav` to a mime type and obviously different browsers map it differently. Thats why they don't have the same mime type. However this is ok. Your mistake is that you expect the same mime type for the same file, however there is no reason to expect this. So I don't have a source because the question is wrong. You ask why they sent a different mime type, but there is no reason why it should be the same!

Comment: We need to review how this works https://addpipe.com/simple-web-audio-recorder-demo/ https://github.com/addpipe/simple-web-audio-recorder-demo