# How does File api determine mime type of a file?

Tags: javascript, html, mime-types

When I use a file input on a HTML form, and use files[0].type, I get mimetype (e.g. images/gif) of the file. How does this api determine the mimetype?
Is it solely based on file extension?

Comment: Maybe implementation dependent, but FF seems to check the file name extension only.

Comment: Yes it is... If you want to perform a better check yourself you can refer to this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672957/3702797)