# how to validate an uploaded image is an image in javascript in html without using extension property

Tags: javascript, html

I've been searching for answers to validate an image which is been uploaded in an html page using  attributes. However, I'm only getting the answers to validate using file extensions. But I need to validate the image by any other properties.

Cause what if a person upload a text file with the file extension edited to any image file extension like text.jpeg. To avoid this I need help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check file MIME type with javascript before upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload)

Comment: Like what propperty? the extention is normal way to look if an image is acceptable. You may wanna look at it's size (say an image below 1kb is not allowed)

Comment: @Dorvalla Usually you look also to MimeType

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check the magic numbers of the file.
Here is a guide to do it in Javascript 
https://medium.com/the-everyday-developer/detect-file-mime-type-using-magic-numbers-and-javascript-16bc513d4e1e