# How to detect a mislabeled WebP file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, webp

I am accepting new files like this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" required>
```

I do not currently have a converter in place, so webp images that are uploaded will not work when displayed on ios or Safari. To combat this, I added the jpg, png, and gif "accept" attribute.

However, if a user renames a webp as one of the accepted files, my file picker won't detect the mislabel, but it will still be a webp and therefore broken as described.

Is there a better way to check the file type using html or javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check file MIME type with javascript before upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload) (Hopefully you can extract a usable answer, it seems it's very similar.)

Comment: Yes, the answer provided by @lmiguelmh worked for me. I did not know to refer to this underlying file type as the MIME type. Thanks!