# How to "correctly" detect mime type of a WEBP image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webp

I am writing a Google Chrome plugin which among other things will detect the format of images on a given web page.

Consider a html image such as:

This:

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;" src="https://media.volkswagen.com/vw-122-my2020/iris?COSY-EU-100-1713VV%25lXm0kYNazzSU9mu0fO7ANiyyJ1vTvsd2SMppEKhjTtKSK8CgQ2MM8H2Lvyr0Q%25UOVggAa5hP4KYwqeQeOOnxvyyJ8H3WDZ4HvCJii8YMNCoo0gZrnZlO4O6bLKKFNMbTggAcEvvFHOu5ZxxHlZkPF%25uAnW07ZZU8pVfXLibIIrsJYUF7xhCCtBvyrm3xLLyH0kYbAwh88WTU9j%25I4bBMdfAA2Zjeqz5qMZKMI7UbSK8C7g1AbNCxDAONX4jTLrr9UOXs3OTMttOWqF55PH4w99deVCZZsoHRiiIVBNffQ00q22Ucp%25nn4h1EuugO4q00zJSYFF3ZhUxxcGfDBBhqCKTTkRkJWWHrqDGGK60cJJMgEhllvPvwEELE5jVVbVlPXXYNgottOQpv55PSSI99dKF7ZZsnQ9iiIVsXffQbVP22UdIVnn4yLOuug9fq00z49YFF3yEkxxc8RqBBhJLdTTklRzWWHrrgGGKOqjJJMFIyllvRFnEEL6AaVVbamRXXYezGttOWDJ55Pjaw99d2gQZZsn5UiiI1ZZffQoKr22UrX0nn4ty9uugmUr00zbluFF3lTkxxcfmhBBhLPRTTkiB%25WWHWsDGGK0BQJJMFWhllvKdYEELxAEVVbXBYXXYrSAttOUtv55P5OI99dJ5UZZsonUiiIuHwffQXmP22UjWnnn4Bb2uugm3c00zj7AFF3FhsxxcGAjBBhpcdTTkdT1WWHur4GGK46jJJMRI%25llvqRkEELAY6VVbco1XXY69mttOUue55PHVS&amp;width=420">
```

Or this:

```
<img width="320" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.webp" alt="WebP Image" border="1">
```

Both links point to an image of .webp format however, the issue is that the first link (despite linking to a .webp image) when evaluated by my program returns a mime type of image/png (it should be image/webp).

In order to determine the mime type of images I am using the [file-type library](https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type). This library detects the mime type of an image from its source by comparing its file signature with a list of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). This technique is outlined here [How to check file MIME type with javascript before upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload)

The code is as follows:

```
const fileType = require("file-type");

const imageLinks = [
"https://media.volkswagen.com/vw-122-my2020/iris?COSY-EU-100-1713VV%25lXm0kYNazzSU9mu0fO7ANiyyJ1vTvsd2SMppEKhjTtKSK8CgQ2MM8H2Lvyr0Q%25UOVggAa5hP4KYwqeQeOOnxvyyJ8H3WDZ4HvCJii8YMNCoo0gZrnZlO4O6bLKKFNMbTggAcEvvFHOu5ZxxHlZkPF%25uAnW07ZZU8pVfXLibIIrsJYUF7xhCCtBvyrm3xLLyH0kYbAwh88WTU9j%25I4bBMdfAA2Zjeqz5qMZKMI7UbSK8C7g1AbNCxDAONX4jTLrr9UOXs3OTMttOWqF55PH4w99deVCZZsoHRiiIVBNffQ00q22Ucp%25nn4h1EuugO4q00zJSYFF3ZhUxxcGfDBBhqCKTTkRkJWWHrqDGGK60cJJMgEhllvPvwEELE5jVVbVlPXXYNgottOQpv55PSSI99dKF7ZZsnQ9iiIVsXffQbVP22UdIVnn4yLOuug9fq00z49YFF3yEkxxc8RqBBhJLdTTklRzWWHrrgGGKOqjJJMFIyllvRFnEEL6AaVVbamRXXYezGttOWDJ55Pjaw99d2gQZZsn5UiiI1ZZffQoKr22UrX0nn4ty9uugmUr00zbluFF3lTkxxcfmhBBhLPRTTkiB%25WWHWsDGGK0BQJJMFWhllvKdYEELxAEVVbXBYXXYrSAttOUtv55P5OI99dJ5UZZsonUiiIuHwffQXmP22UjWnnn4Bb2uugm3c00zj7AFF3FhsxxcGAjBBhpcdTTkdT1WWHur4GGK46jJJMRI%25llvqRkEELAY6VVbco1XXY69mttOUue55PHVS&amp;width=420",
"https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.webp"
]

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + imageLinks[0] // or imageLinks[1]);
                xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

                xhr.onload = () => {
                    var arrayBuffer = xhr.response;
                    if (arrayBuffer) {
                        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
                        imgTypeInfo = fileType(byteArray);
                    }
                };
                xhr.send();
```

```
console.log(imgTypeInfo) // This should return image/webp for both imageLink[0] and imageLink[1]
```

However unfortunately

```
console.log(imgTypeInfo) // This actually returns image/png for imageLinks[0] and image/webp for imageLink[1]
```

Does anybody have any idea why this might be?

For additional context, I have added a link to the github repository [here](https://github.com/Rajeev-Gill/phd-seo-tools/tree/phd-seo-tools-v1.3)

Comment: When I load that Volkswagen image with the insane URL, the `Content-Type` header is "img/png". I suggest that it actually *is* a PNG image, not WEBP.

Comment: Similarly when I get the image and check it with `file` on Linux, it's PNG.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Pointy. It is a confusing issue. If you download the volkswagen image you can see it is .webp file format however the Content-Type header is indeed img/png. The file-type library however does not look at the request header to determine mime type and still we get img/png :(

Comment: I *did* download the image, and it's not WEBP, it's PNG. Every image utility on my Ubuntu system thinks it's PNG, so I think it's safe to conclude that.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that it's WEBP?

Comment: Hi pointy, I just downloaded it again. The file I am getting is iris.webp. I would send you a screenshot but I don't know how

Comment: On win10 it says Type of gile: Chrome Dev HTML Document (.webp)

Comment: All I can tell you is that on my up-to-date Ubuntu installation the tools `file`, `identify`, and `gimp` all think that that file is PNG.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu tools do not care what the extension of the file is; they look at the file *content*.  If I rename the file to `iris.webp` the tools will still think it's a PNG file.

Comment: you can detect the image type by reading the header of image. Try searching for answers