# HTML input type="file" doesn't detect ttf, otf, or js, how do I change that?

Tags: javascript, html, events, file-type

HTML input type="file" event doesn't detect ttf, otf, or js, how do I change that? I would like to have mime types working from the start.

Comment: If you remember about that issue, it would be great to clarify what you meant by "doesn't detect". Did you set an `accept` attribute on that? Did you get an empty `.type` on the returned `File` object? Something else?

Comment: Sorry, its been too long now to remember.

Comment: @Quinn Keaveney: I've added a reminder what doesn't work :).  @Kaiido: frankly I'm curious if there is a good (maybe security related) reason why browsers don't detect mime-types correctly for font files (in contrast to image files) when using file inputs. Certainly negligible since modern browsers also accept the generic `application/octet-stream`  for data URLs – probably the most common use case:  generate dataURLs for self contained embedded fonts or displaying them temporarily in your app UI.

Comment: @herrstrietzel mime type detection on file input is a total mess. IIRC they do a mix of magic number detection against the ones that have been registered on the OS and their own list + some shenanigans based on the file extension. So you can end up with all of docx xlsx pptx and other formats that do use zip compression internally being recognized as `.zip` and `.js` files as just `plain/text` etc. And this can change on two computers running the same OS, based only on what 3rd party app they've installed that do register new file types...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (2024) mime-types are not correctly detected by most browsers when loading font files via a `<input type="file">` element.

Where image files are usually detected correctly the returned type is empty for font files such as `.woff2`, `.woff`, `.ttf`,`.otf`.

Javascript files are actually detected – albeit with slightly different mime-type outputs in Firefox `application/x-javascript`, in chromium/blink-based `text/javascript`.

```js
inputFile.addEventListener("input", async(e) => {
  let file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
  let type = file.type;
  mimetype.textContent=!type ? 'none' : type
})
```

```html
<h1>Show file mime-type</h1>
<p><input id="inputFile" type="file"></p>
<p id="mimetype"></p>
```

You can detect a mime type based on the first four bytes in a file header.

The bytes where looking for can be found here ["6.3. Matching a font type pattern"](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#matching-a-font-type-pattern)

The mimetype helper would look something like this

```js
/**
 * based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload/29672957#29672957
 * Add more from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures
 * or https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#matching-an-image-type-pattern
 */
function getMimeTypeFromHeader(headerString) {
  switch (headerString) {
    case "774f4632":
      type = "font/woff2";
      break;

    case "774f4646":
      type = "font/woff";
      break;

    case "0100":
      type = "font/ttf";
      break;

    case "4f54544f":
      type = "font/otf";
      break;

    case "89504e47":
      type = "image/png";
      break;
    case "47494638":
      type = "image/gif";
      break;
    case "ffd8ffe0":
    case "ffd8ffe1":
    case "ffd8ffe2":
      type = "image/jpeg";
      break;
    default:
      type = "unknown";
      break;
  }
  return type;
}
```

As commented by **Kaiido** we can simplify the header extraction by reading only the first four bytes from the file object like so

```js
    let buffer = await file.slice(0, 4).arrayBuffer();
    let header = Array.from(new Uint8Array(buffer))
      .map((val) => {
        return val.toString(16);
      })
      .join("");
```

```js
inputFile.addEventListener("input", async(e) => {
  let file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
  let type = file.type;
  let dataURLPrefix = `data:${type},`;
  let dataUrl;

  /**
   *  no header in file object - check first bytes in file header
   */
  dataUrl = await blobToBase64(file);

  if (!type) {
    let buffer = await file.slice(0, 4).arrayBuffer();
    let header = Array.from(new Uint8Array(buffer))
      .map((val) => {
        return val.toString(16);
      })
      .join("");

    type = getMimeTypeFromHeader(header);
    //prepend correct mime type
    let dataURLNoMime = dataUrl.split('base64,')[1]
    dataUrl = `data:${type};base64,` + dataURLNoMime
  }

  dataUrlOut.value = dataUrl;
});

/**
 * fetched blob to base64
 */
function blobToBase64(blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}


/**
 * based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload/29672957#29672957
 * Add more from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures
 * or https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#matching-an-image-type-pattern
 */
function getMimeTypeFromHeader(headerString) {
  switch (headerString) {
    case "774f4632":
      type = "font/woff2";
      break;

    case "774f4646":
      type = "font/woff";
      break;

    case "0100":
      type = "font/ttf";
      break;

    case "4f54544f":
      type = "font/otf";
      break;

    case "89504e47":
      type = "image/png";
      break;
    case "47494638":
      type = "image/gif";
      break;
    case "ffd8ffe0":
    case "ffd8ffe1":
    case "ffd8ffe2":
      type = "image/jpeg";
      break;
    default:
      type = "unknown";
      break;
  }
  return type;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', 'Open Sans', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0.3em;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 10em;
  resize: vertical
}

img {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<h1>Font file to dataURL simple</h1>
<p><input id="inputFile" type="file"></p>
<textarea id="dataUrlOut"></textarea>
```

As most mime-type lookups (e.g mimesniff.spec or wikipedia) use a padded notation we may also normalize the bytestrings to use

for instance `00 01 00 00` instead of `0100` as (ttf) pattern.

**Example: normalized pattern**

```js
const mimeFromHeader = true;
const mimeLookup = [
  //fonts
  { pattern: "00 01 00 00", type: "font/ttf" },
  { pattern: "4F 54 54 4F", type: "font/otf" },
  { pattern: "77 4F 46 46", type: "font/woff" },
  { pattern: "77 4F 46 32", type: "font/woff2" },

  //images
  { pattern: "FF D8 FF", type: "image/jpeg" },
  { pattern: "89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A", type: "image/png" },
  { pattern: "52 49 46 46 00 00 00 00 57 45 42 50 56 50", type: "image/webp" },
  { pattern: "47 49 46 38 37 61", type: "image/gif" },
  { pattern: "47 49 46 38 39 61", type: "image/gif" },
  { pattern: "42 4D", type: "image/bmp" },
  
  
  //audio/video
    { pattern: "49 44 33", type: "audio/mpeg" },
    { pattern: "4F 67 67 53 00", type: "application/ogg" },
    { pattern: "52 49 46 46 00 00 00 00 57 41 56 45", type: "audio/wave" },
    { pattern: "1a 45 df a3", type: "video/x-matroska" },
    { pattern: "66 74 79 70 69 73 6F 6D", type: "video/mp4" },
    { pattern: "66 74 79 70 4D 53 4E 56", type: "video/mp4" },
    { pattern: "00 00 00 20 66 74 79 70 4D 53 4E 56", type: "video/mp4" },
    { pattern: "00 00 00 20 66 74 79 70 6d", type: "video/mp4" },
  
];



inputFile.addEventListener("input", async (e) => {
  let file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
  let type = file.type;
  let dataURLPrefix = `data:${type},`;
  let dataUrl;
  
  /**
   *  no header in file object - check first bytes in file header
   */
  dataUrl = await blobToBase64(file);
  
  if (!type || mimeFromHeader) {
    // get array buffer from first 4 bytes
    let firstBytes = await file.slice(0, 14).arrayBuffer();

    // stringify to hexadecimal
    let firstBytesString = Array.from(new Uint8Array(firstBytes))
      .map((val) => {
        val = val.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')
        return val
      })
      .join("");

    type = getMimeTypeFromHeader(mimeLookup, firstBytesString);
    
    //replace generic application type with correct mime type
    let dataURLNoMime = dataUrl.split("base64,")[1];
    dataUrl = `data:${type};base64,` + dataURLNoMime;

  }

  dataUrlOut.value = dataUrl;
});

/**
 * based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload/29672957#29672957
 * Add more from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures
 * or https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#matching-an-image-type-pattern
 */

function getMimeTypeFromHeader(mimeLookup, headerString) {
  
  /**
  * helper to normalize to longhand/padded first byte notations
  */
  const firstByteStringify = (str) => {
    let strArr = str.split(" ");
    let byteString;
    if (strArr.length > 1) {
      byteString = str
        .split(" ")
        .map((val) => {
        return val.toString(16).padStart(2, '0').toLowerCase()
        })
        .join("");
    } else {
      byteString = str.toLowerCase();
    }
    return byteString;
  };
  

  let mimeType = "";
  
  for (let i = 0; i < mimeLookup.length && !mimeType; i++) {
    let mime = mimeLookup[i];
    let pattern = firstByteStringify(mime.pattern);
    let lenMin = Math.min(pattern.length, headerString.length)
    
    // has riff - check last bytes:
    let riff= headerString.substring(0, 8);
    let hasRiff = riff==='52494646'
    
    // adjust pattern and header length if shorter than 4 bytes or has riff
    pattern = hasRiff ? pattern.substring(pattern.length -12) :  pattern.substring(0, lenMin);
    let headerShort = hasRiff ? headerString.substring(headerString.length -12) : headerString.substring(0, lenMin);

    
    if (headerShort === pattern) {
      mimeType = mime.type;
    }
  }
  return mimeType;
}


/**
 * fetched blob to base64
 */
function blobToBase64(blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', 'Open Sans', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0.3em;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 10em;
  resize: vertical
}

img {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<h1>Font file to dataURL simple</h1>
<p><input id="inputFile" type="file"></p>
<textarea id="dataUrlOut"></textarea>
```

See also this answer ["How to check file MIME type with JavaScript before upload?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload/29672957#29672957)

Comment: Why read the whole file if you're only gonna use the first 4 bytes? `file.slice(0, 4)` is enough.

Comment: Good point (as always!) I was actually investigating on more efficient approaches – so thanks for the shortcut! I'll update the post soon

Answer (score -2):

Try this for JS.

```
    <form action="">
    <label for="file">Select file:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="text/js">
    </form>
```

**Info on accept**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#attr-accept

**Configuring server MIME types**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Configuring_server_MIME_types

**MIME types**

https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/

Comment: I'm not looking to support accept. I want ttf and otf to be reflected in the mime type.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Configuring_server_MIME_types