# Get File type in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, input

**In react**

```js
const allInputs = { imgUrl: '' };
const [imageAsFile, setImageAsFile] = useState('');
const [imageAsUrl, setImageAsUrl] = useState(allInputs);
const [media, setMedia] = useState(null);

const handleImageAsFile = (e) => {
    const image = e.target.files[0]
    setImageAsFile(imageFile => (image));
    console.log(imageAsFile);

}
```

**Here is the input code, when I click this button, all types of files show, but I want to be able to store the *type of file* it is in a variable**

```js
<input type="text"
    id="phone"
    onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
/>
```

For example, if I select an image, how can know the type of image I have selected? If it is png or jpg or whatever before uploading it to the database.

Comment: I think this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload

Comment: Javascript used in react is not the same with the one used for normal html, css and js

Comment: is there an answer that uses hooks in react

Comment: That's something of a new concept you've introduced, You should let javascript run the way it runs

Comment: There's no reason to add hooks in the code to find the type of image, it is completely unncessary.

Comment: ```<input type="file" id="your-files" multiple>
<script>
var control = document.getElementById("your-files");
control.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    // When the control has changed, there are new files
    var files = control.files,
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        console.log("Filename: " + files[i].name);
        console.log("Type: " + files[i].type);
        console.log("Size: " + files[i].size + " bytes");
    }
}, false);
</script>```

React doesnt work like this

Comment: React doesn't use scripts tag, and what works in the script tag doesnt work the same way in react,

Comment: use the type property on your image variable i.e image.type, will work, If you want I can write an answer for this

Comment: please, i'll appreciate an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, React Javascript works the exact way Javascript works everywhere, For accessing the image type refer to the below code, I have added the comments for better understanding.

```
const [imageAsFile, setImageAsFile] = useState('');
    const [imageAsUrl, setImageAsUrl] = useState(allInputs);
    const [media, setMedia] = useState(null);

 const handleImageAsFile = (e) => {
     //image var holds the file object which has a type property 
      const image = e.target.files[0];          
      console.log(image.type); // this will output the mime, i.e "image/png" or "image/jpg"
      setImageAsFile(imageFile => (image));
     console.log(imageAsFile);

  }
```