# Javascript: Find out image format of a blob

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing

Given a  tag with src to a blob representing an image, how can I know its format/file type? (png,jpg and so on)

Assuming the src itself doesn't contain any file extension that can help with that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload/29672957#29672957

Comment: Have you tried blob.type? This should return the MIME type of the image. If it is unknown then you will get back an empty string.