# React - The downloaded pdf is not opening

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create a pdf file from Blob, I am not able to open the pdf

```
 axios.get(url, {responseType: 'blob'}).then((response) => {
   FileDownload(response.data, 'test.pdf');
})
```

Getting the following error
Unable to open pdf. type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported

Comment: does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload

Comment: @FarshadKazemi It explains only image types

Comment: In the answer, you can find an example that uses browser for all the files.