How to check if a result is a document?
I am using JavaScript that makes a call to a server (Java) to get documents. It has an Ajax call:
Client (JavaScript):
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: urlStringCustomerInvoices,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.length > 0) {

The server (Java) sets a byte array representing the PDF document (can also be other document types):
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
bos.write(bytes);
bos.flush();
os.flush();
os.close();

This works as expected, i.e. a document, e.g. PDF can be downloaded sucessfully. However, when there is a problem, I want to be able handle it. If the returned result is not a valid document.
On the client in JavaScript, how do I validate if the returned result is a valid document?
Valid documents are file types .pdf, .doc and .docx
The type seems to always be String:
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(result));

prints:
[object String]

Also:
console.log(result.length);

prints (for a valid PDF):
66402


What is your definition of "not a valid document"?

If it is not a PDF or DOC type file

Would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload/29672957#29672957 an option for you?

If the server responds with a correct Content-Type, then you could check on that. (The success callback gets an jqXHR instance passed as 3rd parameter, and that has a getResponseHeader method - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

You can get the MIME type in the header and then check for contentType
    success: function (result, status, xhr) {
            var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
            if (contentType === "application/pdf" || 
                contentType === "application/msword"
                // you can add more types 
) {
                // Valid document
                console.log("valid doc");
            } else {
                // Handle error
                console.error("invalid doc or error");
            }
        }

 


This does require the Content-Type to be properly set from the server. I.e. merely writing bytes to the output stream isn't going to cut it.
