# How to Identify a File is image or not in PHP

Tags: php, server

I have tried with `getimagesize()` , `finfo` and getting Mime type function. But I have noticed we can not trust on these function as I observed it's fails in my case for some image files. Do we have any better way to identify a file is image or not. 
Use case  : I have one file with php code inside it. I have saved this file with some image extension. Now I want to block this file from getting uploaded.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15408176/3476207

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uploaded file type check by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755192/uploaded-file-type-check-by-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try php's inbuilt method to check image type,

```
int exif_imagetype ( string $filename )
```

This method returns `false` if file is not a valid image otherwise will return an Integer pointing to the type of image.

Also it throws a notice. So you may do something like this.

```
if(@exif_imagetype($file)){
     //Valid Image
} else {
     // Invalid
}
```

Comment: I tried this but if you save a file contains some script with some image extension then also it's returns valid image

Comment: it should not, can you paste the content of file.

Comment: looking forward to see what file saved as image extension will return valid image as well. I've tried several forms and it all returns false if it's invalid

Answer (score 0):

i think you should take a look over the

```
mime_content_type
```

or

```
Fileinfo
```

of

```
system("file -bi $uploadedfile")
```

see more detail view over the below post

[How to check file types of uploaded files in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310714/how-to-check-file-types-of-uploaded-files-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code:

```
function is_image($path)
{
    $a = getimagesize($path);
    $image_type = $a[2];

    if(in_array($image_type , array(IMAGETYPE_GIF , IMAGETYPE_JPEG 
    ,IMAGETYPE_PNG , IMAGETYPE_BMP)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your server is running on Linux you should execute `file`:

```
$mime = exec("file $tmpFilePath -z -b --mime-type");
```

This will define mime type correctly